# Netbeans 11 how to add a library to a project when "Libraries" node is missing?

Tags: openjfx, netbeans-11

I am trying to run a simple java fx example with Maven on Netbeans 11 with openjdk 11. I followed the [OpenJfx tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) up to the creation of JavaFx as a global library.

But then when I want to add this global library to my project, the "libraries" node is missing in the project properties menu ?

[image]

How can I have this Libraries node present in the menu ? Or is there another way to add a global library to a project ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

Indeed I was following the part of [OpenJfx tutorial](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans) that creates an Ant project, whereas I was creating a Maven project.

If instead I use an Ant project, then the "libraries" node appears.

But the interesting part for Maven is [further down](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans). And there they write to **create a Maven project from archetype**.

Eventually it is working !

[image]

Comment: so how did you get the library option back?

Comment: Wow it was more than a year ago! I followed the provided link, scrolled down to the Maven section and followed the provided instructions starting with "Create a Maven Project from archetype"!